# Typescript 3.7 Partial and is not assignable to type never/undefined

Tags: typescript

After upgrading typescript version to 3.7 I get type errors in 2 functions. The functions work correctly (when adding @ts-ignore everything is fine).

```
interface A {
    x: string,
    y: number,
}

interface B {
    x: string,
    y: number,
    z: boolean,
}

function extract(input: B, keys: Array<keyof A>): Partial<A> {
    const extract: Partial<A> = {};
    keys.forEach((key: keyof A) => {
        extract[key] = input[key]; // error!
    //  ~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- 'string | number' is not assignable to 'undefined'    
    });
    return extract;
}

function assign(target: B, source: Partial<A>): void {
    (Object.keys(source) as Array<keyof A>).forEach((key) => {
        target[key] = source[key]!; // error!
    //  ~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'
    });
}

const test: B = { x: "x", y: 1, z: true };
console.log(extract(test, ["y"])); // -> { y: 1 }
assign(test, { x: "new" });
console.log(test); // -> { x: "new", y: 1, z: true }
```

The code along with errors can be found at [ts playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=29&pc=53#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-YHg1JEymtSHkHqNMQjSagA)

Is there any way to implement this the right way without @ts-ignore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [known breaking change](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types) introduced in TypeScript 3.5 to prevent unsound writes to indexed access types.  It has had some good effects by catching actual bugs, and it's had some unfortunate effects by falsely warning on perfectly safe assignments, as you can see.

The simplest way to get around this is to use [a type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
(extract as any)[key] = input[key];
(target as any)[key] = source[key];
```

There are safer assertions than `any`, but they are more complicated to express.

---

If you want to avoid type assertions, you'll need to use some workarounds.  For `extract()`, it suffices to use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) callback function inside `forEach()`.  The compiler sees the assignment as being both from and to a value of the *identical* generic type `Partial<A>[K]`, which it allows:

```
function extract(input: B, keys: Array<keyof A>): Partial<A> {
    const extract: Partial<A> = {};
    keys.forEach(<K extends keyof A>(key: K) => {
        extract[key] = input[key];
    });
    return extract;
}
```

For `assign()` that `target[key] = source[key]` won't work even with a generic `key` of type `K`.  You're reading from a generic type `NonNullable<Partial<A>[K]>` and writing to a *different* generic type `B[K]`.  (I mean "different" in the sense that the compiler doesn't represent them identically; of course they are the same type when you evaluate them.)  We can get back the identical type by widening the `target` variable to `Partial<A>` (which is fine because every `B` is also a `Partial<A>`, if you squint and don't think about mutations).

So I'd do it like this:

```
function assign(target: B, source: Partial<A>): void {
    const keys = Object.keys(source) as Array<keyof A>;
    const widerTarget: Partial<A> = target;
    keys.forEach(<K extends keyof A>(key: K) => {
        if (typeof source[key] !== "undefined") { // need this check
            widerTarget[key] = source[key];
        }
    });
}
```

Oh and I added that `undefined` check because `assign(test, { x: "new", y: undefined })` is allowed; the language doesn't really [distinguish missing from `undefined`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195).

---

Anyway, those will work as desired.  Personally I'd probably just use a type assertion and move on.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-Du3yKACMvk00agzBQzSwPP0EHaem0lGcrycYOXYF8O3d9HdY5uofDAFo1goxC7sgvB1sCoKQGQvjrsQ7ogBAvLboByBej6fo4tcLQXgY163k+ZDfmGyD-pgBCwfBiE7kBB7EOQJ4gXwWBAA)

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer!

Comment: I think I understand, why they did it, but I don't understand why it doesn't report the error like *... isn't assignable to type 'unknown'*. Because that's the actual problem. The left hand side's type is unknown at compile time.

Comment: All types are assignable to `unknown`, so that cannot be the error.  The issue is that the only safe operation for an assignment like `foo[bar] = baz` is if the type of `baz` is appropriate for every possible value of `bar`.  Say `foo.x` is a `number` and `foo.y` is a `string`; then `foo[Math.random()<0.5 ? "x" : "y"] = baz` requires that `baz` be both a `string` *and* a `number`, which is not possible... there is no such value.  The type `string & number` is `never`, not `unknown`.  So the error talks about `never` and not `unknown`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution using a helper function:

```
interface A {
    x: string,
    y: number,
}

interface B {
    x: string,
    y: number,
    z: boolean,
}

// Using this method, is better accepted by the transpiler
function typedAssign<T>(source: T, target: Partial<T>, key: keyof T, force: boolean = false) {
    if (force) {
        target[key] = source[key]!;
    } else {
        target[key] = source[key];
    }
}

function extract(input: B, keys: Array<keyof A>): Partial<A> {
    const extract: Partial<Pick<B, keyof A>> = {};
    keys.forEach((key: keyof A) => {
        typedAssign(input, extract, key);
    });
    return extract;
}

function assign(target: B, source: Partial<A>): void {
    (Object.keys(source) as Array<keyof A>).forEach((key) => {
        typedAssign(source, target, key, true);
    });
}

const test: B = { x: "x", y: 1, z: true };
console.log(extract(test, ["y"])); // -> { y: 1 }
assign(test, { x: "new" });
console.log(test); // -> { x: "new", y: 1, z: true }
```

TS Playground:
http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=37&pc=53#